# How come Javascript arrays can hold multiple data-types at same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I've just picked up javaScript and i am amazed to see that javaScript arrays can hold any type of data in them, for example, a number and a string both can be stored in a single array. well, i've always studied in my Data Structures classes that "Array is a container which can hold fix number of items and these items should be of *same type*". My question is :- Is javascript a special case? or, they have changed the definition of array?

Comment: That's the way the language works. Any variable or object property can hold a value of any type.

Comment: JavaScript _variables_ can hold any datatype.`var a = 1; a = "bob"; a = [1, "bob"]`. It's pretty much consistent in that JS doesn't really care.

Comment: You were probably use a language with strong typing for your Data Structures course, and the definition of an array they gave you was specific for that course. It is also a bad definition since it is missing the concept of order. A map is also a collection of items, but without order. A broad definition for an array is: An *array* is an ordered list. Of course there are other things like linked lists that are data structures that aren't typically considered to be arrays, but they are ordered lists. Arrays are typically ordered lists that are indexed by integers.

Comment: @R.k.Anand questions like "why is language X like Y" are somewhat pointless; who knows the answer? It's a design decision made 20 years ago. That's the way it works. Note that many other languages work that way too - it's not unique to JavaScript.

Comment: @R.k.Anand JavaScript arrays are also not fixed size, they expand automatically as you add elements to them.

Comment: JavaScript is hardly unique in this respect. The same thing is true in PHP, Python, Lisp, and other languages. The thing they all have in common is that types are associated with values rather than with variables and containers. A common term is that these languages are "weakly typed", while languagues like C are "strongly typed".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting Mozilla JS Reference on this:

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform
>   traversal and mutation operations. **Neither the length of a JavaScript
>   array nor the types of its elements are fixed.**

More on this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now my doubts are cleared. Actually, in javascript an array is not a data-structure instead it is an object and hence can contain any type of data. I found one more link which was also very helpful. [link](http://net-informations.com/faq/netfaq/multipledata.htm). Although it is in context of C#, it can be related.

Comment: The term array is often used to mean array data type, a kind of data type provided by most high-level programming languages that consists of a collection of values or variables that can be selected by one or more indices computed at run-time. Array types are often implemented by array structures; however, in some languages they may be implemented by hash tables, linked lists, search trees, or other data structures. src: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure